# How do I print '2' in star pattern in C?

Tags: c

I want to print a '2' in a star pattern like:

```
*****
    *
*****
*
*****
```

I tried this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j;

    for(i=1; i<=5; i++)
    {
        
        for(j=1; j<=5; j++)
        {
            if(i==1 || i==5 || j==1 || j==5 || i==3)
            {
                        printf("*");
                    
                }
                
            else
            {
                printf(" ");
            }
        }

        
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But it gives me this output:

```
*****
*   *
*****
*   *
*****
```

So, I know I need to remove the first * in the 2nd line and the last star in 4th line to achieve my desired output. The problem is that I've no idea how to do that. So, please guide me on how to achieve the desired output.

I've tried doing

```
if(i!==2 && j!==1)
printf("*");
```

but that doesn't work and completely messes up the whole thing.

So, please guide me guys.

Comment: Why not compose the string "manually" and print it out? Surely will be faster and less code.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. it's actually an assignment given to us to build this pattern using for loops.

Comment: Surely loops can be used with more sense :(

Comment: Anyway, you still can have an array of 5 strings and print them in a loop. If it satisfies the requirements of course.

Comment: No, I have to do it this way.. using loops and if else statements.

Comment: There are fewer spaces than stars, so you should write the condition to determine when to print a space, and the `else` should print the stars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```c
int main()
{
    int i, j;

    for(i=1; i<=5; i++)
    {
        for(j=1; j<=5; j++)
        {
            if(i == 1 || i == 3 || i == 5){
                printf("*");
            }
            else if (i == 2 && j == 5){
                printf("*");
            }
            else if (i == 4 && j == 1){
                printf("*");
            }else {
                printf(" ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (i == 1 || i == 3 || i == 5)` maybe use modulo `if (i%2)`  ?

Comment: You can combine if-clauses into a single one or  i % 2 These tricks seem very nice. I think they affect code readability bad way.

Answer (score 2):

If you plan to print other symbols like that, you may want to separate the symbol representations and the printout:

```
const short data[][2] = {{0, 5}, {4, 1}, {0, 5}, {0, 1}, {0, 5}};
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < data[i][0]; j++) putchar('*');
    for(j = 0; j < data[i][1]; j++) putchar(' ');
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in many ways. Here's one of them

```
for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
    
    puts("*****");
    
    if( i == 0 ) {
        puts("    *");
    }
    else if( i == 1 ) {
        puts("*");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. that's pretty clever and I learned a new technique with this so Thanks a lot. But I'll have to accept İsmal's answer as that's the one that I know my teacher wants to see lol. But, still thanks a lot for this.

Answer (score 0):

Put some more conditionals in that if statement:

```
...
for(j=1; j<=5; j++)
        {
            if(i==1 || i==5 || (j==1 && i==4) || (j==5 && i==2) || i==3)
            {
                        printf("*");
                    
                }
...
```

Comment: That doesn't work.. I'm still getting the same output

Comment: That's strange, I copied in my modified if statement and got exactly what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would prefer a functional approach for sure, but there you go:

```html
if(i==1 || i==3 || i==5 || (j == 1 && i == 4) || (j == 5 && i == 2))
```

Comment: New user here, I could not commented on his post. What lil' wing shared is true. Did you try to recompile the new code? You might be trying to run your own old code.

Answer (score 0):

**I hope I could help you**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() 
{
int i;
bool position=true; 
for(i=0 ; i<5 ; i++)
{
    if(i%2==0)
        printf("*****\n");
    if(i%2==1)
    {
        if(position==true)
        {
            printf("    *\n");
        }
        if(position==false)
        {
            printf("*    \n");
        }
        position = !position;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```